# How to hide and show image caption for multiple image using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

i have structure like below,

```
<div class="btheme">    
    <a href="/a1"><img src="/a1.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="caption">
         <div>image caption</div>
    </div>   
</div>


<div class="btheme">    
   <a href="/a3"><img src="/a3.jpg" /></a>
   <div class="caption">
       <div>image caption3</div>
   </div>   
</div>


<div class="btheme">    
   <a href="/a2"><img src="/a2.jpg" /></a>
   <div class="caption">
      <div>image caption2</div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

i used below code for show / hide caption in jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

         jQuery("div.btheme .img").mouseover(function(){
              jQuery(this).parent().find("div.caption").css('display','none');              
         });

         jQuery("div.btheme .img").mouseout(function(){
             jQuery(this).parent().find("div.caption").css('display','block');              
         });                
   });

  </script>
```

it does not work?. how can i do this?.

Comment: Do you want the caption to be displayed on `mouseover` or `mouseout`?

Comment: the caption displayed on bottom of the image(above the image).

Comment: I'm talking about the event, not the location. BTW i've added a fiddle with my answer.

Comment: on mouse over need to display...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dot in front of `.img`.

Also, for selecting the caption div, use this instead:

```
jQuery(this).closest("div.btheme").find("div.caption")...
```

`jQuery(this).parent()` will give you the anchor tag which is wrong.

**Update:**
Here is the working code in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ZH3/).

Comment: working fine. But when i mouse over the caption it is continuously blinking. what is the issue?

Comment: Could you post your code in jsfiddle so we can see the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Only `img` not `.img`

```
jQuery("div.btheme img").mouseover(function(){
   jQuery(this).parent().next("div.caption").css('display','none');
});

jQuery("div.btheme img").mouseout(function(){
   jQuery(this).parent().next("div.caption").css('display','block');    
});
```

Comment: not working. the div's has same calssname..that is the problem?.

Comment: how can i do this slidedown and slideup for this